# Spark changes column nullability after join

Tags: apache-spark

I have three dataframes with specified schemas. Before joining all columns are nullable. However, after a (left outer) join, even columns which do not have udf applied on them, change their nullability. And I don't see any logic how they change it. Not all columns become not nullable. 
Did someone encounter this?

Basically, I do something like this:

```
val joinedDf = broadcast (df1).join(df2, col("idInDf1")===col("idInDf2"), "left_outer").join(df3, col("idInDf1")===col("idInDf3),"left_outer")
```

Comment: can you share your code snippet?

Comment: I have added example.

Comment: I don't think it is duplicate. I initially have dataframes, and join also as dataframes. I would suspect that `broadcast` or other function affect,but there are columns which are not affected by any. And still become not nullable.

Comment: Can you add some input/output example as well as the schema before and after?